# Simple plot using matplotlib in Python2.7 on 32bit Fedora gives OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have this simple code to test matplotlib using Python 2.7 in Fedora 23 32bit.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [20, 21, 20.5, 20.8]

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

which gives the following output:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1536, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 278, in resize
    self.show()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 350, in draw
    tkagg.blit(self._tkphoto, self.renderer._renderer, colormode=2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 21, in blit
    _tkagg.tkinit(tk.interpaddr(), 1)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Any ideas what is wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: Your code should work fine, but perhaps something is wrong with your matplotlib installation? Maybe try reinstalling it?

Comment: Tried this, no success.

Comment: Note that this problem is not there when using Fedora 23 64bit. Perhaps a bug in matplotlib 32bit?

Comment: Could be. Did you get the error when using the version installed via the Fedora repos?

Comment: Yes this was installed using dnf

Comment: You could try installing it directly from PyPI using pip, maybe there is something wrong with the 32-bit Fedora package.